# Can someone explain what are strong updates and give an example which illustrates it?

Tags: c, pointers, heap-memory, variable-assignment

I'm reading the [Strong Update](http://suif.stanford.edu/papers/wilson95/subsection3_4_1.html#SECTION0004100000000000000) section of a paper on *Efficient Context-Sensitive Pointer Analysis for C Programs* and I'm not able to grasp exactly what it means. Can someone provide an example, especially for this line in the link:

> This greatly improves our ability to perform strong updates. Since a heap block represents all the storage allocated in a particular context, we assume that locally allocated heap blocks are never unique.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Strong update, weak update

In the context of static analysis, where one is trying to infer all possible behaviors of the program at once, a *strong update* is an update (assignment) operation in which the address being updated is known precisely. By contrast, an assignment where the address written to is not known precisely is called a *weak update*.

When handling a weak update, not only the new value can be written at several locations and it is not known which, but in addition, the possibility must be considered that each location keeps its old value (since the update may happen elsewhere).

### Example

Consider [Frama-C's value analysis](http://frama-c.com/try_out_value.html), an efficient context-sensitive pointer analysis for C programs available as a package in most Linux distributions. Let us say that we are analyzing the following program:

```
int a, b, c, d, *p, t[5];

int main(int argc, char **argv){
  a = 1; // strong
  p = &b;
  *p = 2; // strong
  if (c & 1) 
    p = &c;
  else
    p = &d;
  *p = 3; // weak

  t[2] = 4; // strong
  t[c & 2] = 5; // weak
}
```

When analyzing this example with Frama-C's value analysis, one gets:

```
$ frama-c -val t.c
[value] Values at end of function main:
  a ∈ {1}
  b ∈ {2}
  c ∈ {0; 3}
  d ∈ {0; 3}
  p ∈ {{ &c ; &d }}
  t[0] ∈ {0; 5}
   [1] ∈ {0}
   [2] ∈ {4; 5}
   [3..4] ∈ {0}
  __retres ∈ {0}
```

The locations `c`, `d`, `t[0]` and `t[2]` have been the target of a weak update. They each can contain either a new value (that could have been written there) or an old value (that was there at the time and could have remained).

By opposition, `a` and `b` have been the object of a strong update. It was known that the assignment was writing exactly to each of these variables, so there is no need to consider the possibility they might have kept their old values.

### In the context of the article

Regarding the precise paragraph that you cite:

> The key is to recognize that an extended parameter representing the
>   initial value of a unique pointer can be a unique block even if that
>   pointer has many possible values in the calling context. Since the
>   pointer can only contain one of those possibilities at any one time,
>   the extended parameter is a unique block within the scope of the
>   procedure. Only when more than one location points to an extended
>   parameter and the actual values for that parameter are not a single
>   unique location must we mark the parameter as not unique. This greatly
>   improves our ability to perform strong updates.

The researchers aim at using the strong update as often as possible, since it is more precise. In this paragraph, they remark that although a pointer `p` may point to several possible locations, if you give a name to “the location `p` points to”, then you can strongly update that location. I think this is what they are saying.

This would allow, in my example program, to read from `*p` at the end of the program and to find that it contains exactly `3`, although `p` points to `c` that may contain `0` or `3` or to `d` that may contain `0` or `3`. Older versions of Frama-C's value analysis inferred this information with a technique similar to that described (if I understand it correctly) but it was too expensive and was removed.